# fancybox loads ok... then when page finishes loading its thrown off and changes position

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, wordpress

I've tried to look at my site's code using chromes debug tool to see why this is happening but to no avail.

Basically.

Im using fancybox for wordpress so that when a user clicks on an image it expands into a pretty lightbox.

Currently whilst the page is loading still if i click an image fancybox loads ok, but as soon as the page finishes loading fancybox is positioned to the right and the overlay only shows up on the site content (not whole browser screen) im wondering if there is a way to see what is causing this or if someone knows a fix :( would be greatly appreciated.

http://bit.ly/17k4Ef1

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, is not a good idea to set `size`, `position`  and/or `margins` to the `body` and the `html` tags but use wrapper containers instead.

Your issue is caused because `body` has

```
element.style {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
```

... css properties.

Remove them as a test and you'll see everything is back to normal.